# Using try with resources in Java

Tags: java

WhenI use try with resources in a program written in Java 8, [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), is it still necessary or a good practice to close files explicitly?

Comment: It then becomes a good practice _not_ to close things IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation you linked: "Note: A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run **after the resources declared have been closed**."

So, no.  You don't need to.